# How to Apply RTL Support to Shadcn Components in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, next-i18next, radix-ui

I'm using Next.js app version 14.
RTL is not applied to Shadcn components.
I'm also using next-intl to support multiple languages
Here's how my layout.tsx file looks like:

```
layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import "../globalsyour text.css";

import localFont from "next/font/local";
import { Provider } from "../../providers";
import { NextIntlClientProvider, useMessages } from "next-intl";

const iranSansFont = localFont({
  src: "../../fonts/iranSans.woff2",
  display: "swap",
  variable: "--font-iranSans",
});

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
  params: { locale },
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactElement;
  params: { locale: string };
}>) {
  const messages = useMessages();

  return (
    <html lang={locale} dir={locale === "fa" ? "rtl" : "ltr"}>
      <body
        className={`${iranSansFont.className} bg-background text-foreground px-4 py-4 font-bold`}
      >
        <NextIntlClientProvider locale={locale} messages={messages}>
          <Provider>{children}</Provider>
        </NextIntlClientProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Additionally, I've utilized @radix-ui/react-direction, but encountered the following error.

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import "../globals.css";

import localFont from "next/font/local";
import { Provider } from "../../providers";
import { NextIntlClientProvider, useMessages } from "next-intl";
import { DirectionProvider } from "@radix-ui/react-direction";

const iranSansFont = localFont({
  src: "../../fonts/iranSans.woff2",
  display: "swap",
  variable: "--font-iranSans",
});

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
  params: { locale },
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactElement;
  params: { locale: string };
}>) {
  const messages = useMessages();

  return (
    <html lang={locale} dir={locale === "fa" ? "rtl" : "ltr"}>
      <body
        className={`${iranSansFont.className} bg-background text-foreground px-4 py-4 font-bold`}
      >
        <DirectionProvider dir={locale === "fa" ? "rtl" : "ltr"}>
          <NextIntlClientProvider locale={locale} messages={messages}>
            <Provider>{children}</Provider>
          </NextIntlClientProvider>
        </DirectionProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Error:
⨯ node_modules@radix-ui\react-direction\dist\index.mjs (4:82) @ undefined
⨯ TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function
at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-direction/dist/index.mjs:9:114)
at (rsc)/./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-direction/dist/index.mjs (C:\Users\ehsanKey\Documents\dev\portfolio-site.next\server\vendor-chunks@radix-ui.js:260:1)
at **webpack_require** (C:\Users\ehsanKey\Documents\dev\portfolio-site.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/[locale]/layout.tsx:14:83)
at (rsc)/./src/app/[locale]/layout.tsx (C:\Users\ehsanKey\Documents\dev\portfolio-site.next\server\app[locale]\page.js:374:1)
at Function.**webpack_require** (C:\Users\ehsanKey\Documents\dev\portfolio-site.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async collectGenerateParams (C:\Users\ehsanKey\Documents\dev\portfolio-site\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:919:21)
at async Object.loadStaticPaths (C:\Users\ehsanKey\Documents\dev\portfolio-site\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\static-paths-worker.js:46:13) {
type: 'TypeError',
page: ''
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this error by wrapping `DirectionProvider` with a component that is marked with `'use client'` (see [the Next.js docs on 3rd party providers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#using-third-party-packages-and-providers)).